# Spring 3 Declarative transaction support in HTTP Servlet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, http, servlets

I need to do a  spring transaction in core Http Servlet. But it seems spring transaction is not working .I have annotated my servlet with @component to register it as spring bean.  I have also annotated following method with necessary annotations required for  declarative transaction.
The following  method is called from doGet(req,res) method of core servlet.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
private String sendContractDetials(String tran) throws IOException  {
     customerDAO.remove(customer);
}
```

Can some body please tell me how to add spring transaction support in core http servlet or some other work around.

Comment: Why don't you extract the code out of your servlet, put it in a class, call the doGet() method from the Controller by passing request, response.... This way you will have more precise control over it, you could simply declare that class as a bean and use it...Then you wont have issues with Transaction management.

Comment: I know it can work like this but i want to add Spring Transaction Management with Http Servlet.

Comment: Also, if you are just calling one line in your servlet, its much more efficient to annotate the CustomerDAOImpl rather than the servlet. But your wish.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `Transactional` annotation is not magic. For this to work you would need to weave your code either during compile time or at runtime.

Have you added `<tx:annotation-driven/>` element in your spring-context.xml configuration file?

Comment: yes i did add this annotation in my applicationContext.xml file.